# Better way to write this query in order to convert it into laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have prepared this query but unable to convert it to laravel eloquent. I need help to find out if there is a better way to write this query in order.

Below is the query

https://gist.github.com/thedesignerkumar/ef9062efb262ec9c128f4832af32d3e2

```
SELECT
    rooms.location,
    rooms.id,
    rooms.`name`,
    users.name,
    IF(
      (
        bookings.`status` = 'booked' AND(
          NOT(
            bookings.end_time <= '2017-05-30 12:00:00' OR bookings.start_time >= '2017-05-30 12:35:00'
            ) OR(
            bookings.recurring = 1 AND DATE(bookings.start_time) <= '2017-05-30' AND NOT(
              TIME(bookings.end_time) <= '12:00:00' OR TIME(bookings.start_time) >= '12:35:00'
              )
            )
            )
        ),
      'Booked',
      'Available'
      ) AS 'Status',
    bookings.recurring,
    bookings.start_time,
    bookings.end_time
    FROM
    rooms
    LEFT JOIN
    bookings
    ON
    rooms.id = bookings.room_id
    LEFT JOIN
    users
    ON
    bookings.user_id = users.id
    ORDER BY
    STATUS
    DESC
    ,
    bookings.start_time ASC,
    rooms.id ASC
```

Comment: What is this query supposed to do?

Comment: find all the rooms and then find their booking status (if any) with their user details based on user specified time slots

Comment: Hm, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent isn't the only method of querying a database in Laravel. Eloquent is just the ORM that comes with Laravel. Eloquent itself is built on the [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) class that also comes with Laravel.

You can certainly rebuild your query using the query builder but a more efficient method would be to user your existing query like so: `DB::select($query)`.

If you choose to just put your query directly into `DB::select()` rather than rebuilding it with the QueryBuilder you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You'll need to handle these prior to building the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am already using DB::select($query) method and as per laravel documentation, it provides a way to use placeholders so it should not be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I think you are confusing this with DB::raw($query) which opens the gate for sql injections.